# The probability of putting $n$ balls into $r$ distinguishable boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we randomly distribute $n$ balls into $r$ distinguishable boxes. The problem is to determine the probability that each box contains at least one ball.

I was asked whether the balls should be taken to be distinguishable or indistinguishable in this question. Those who I have asked say that this probability is 'obviously' independent of whether the balls are distinguishable or not. I agreed with this on an intuitive basis, but when I tried to prove this using the elementary formula for probability (no. of successful outcomes/no. of possible outcomes) I obtained an apparent contradiction.

In the distinguishable case, the probability is $\dfrac{r!{n\brace r}}{r^n}$.

In the indistinguishable case, the probability is $\dfrac{\binom{n-1}{r-1}}{\binom{n+r-1}{n}}$.

(Here, the curly braces denote a Stirling number of the second kind.) These two expressions are not equal.

I am not sure if I've made a silly error and the above expressions aren't correct, I'm missing something more subtle, or it is simply not true that the probability is independent of whether the balls are distinguishable. It is strange that such an elementary problem is confusing me so much. Please could someone clear this up.

**EDIT**: Having thought about this for some time, I think I have identified the (somewhat subtle) problem. I have noticed that when the balls are indistinguishable, the various configurations are NOT equally likely, thus we cannot use the elementary probability formula. Where when the balls are distinguishable, they are, so we can use the formula (this is all assuming that for a given ball, each box is equally likely, and the balls are independent). Thus in the indistinguishable case, we need to compute the probability in a different way. This should then turn out to be the same as the formula we get from the distinguishable case, namely $\dfrac{r!{n\brace r}}{r^n}$. I suspect that PIE will do this.

**EDIT 2**: Hopefully I've finally sorted this out. I believe that distinguishability of the balls is irrelevant for computing the probabilities of any particular configurations. The reason is that the probability model should be that the balls are just $n$ independent and identically distributed discrete random variables taking values from $1$ to $r$ (depending on which box they go into), each with probability $1/r$. And then the probability of any given configuration of balls in boxes must be the number of such configurations where the balls are distinguishable divided by $r^n$. The reason the other formula doesn't work is that (under this model) the different configurations are not equally likely when the balls are not distinguished.

Comment: I don't understand your computation in the distinguishable case.  Consider the case $n=r=2$ Suppose we had balls $b_1, b_2$.  The "good" arrangements are $(b_1,b_2)$ and $(b_2,b_1)$, each of which has probability $\frac 14$, making the answer $\frac 12$.  But you get $\binom 11\Big / \binom 32=\frac 13$, or am I  misunderstanding?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wrote the cases the wrong way round. I edited in the correction. So here it would in fact be $\frac{1}{3}$ because the arrangements $(b_1,b_2)$ and $(b_2,b_1)$ would be the same and then there would only be two other possibilities, namely both balls in either bucket (which would be distinct because the buckets are distinct).

Comment: Your answers are now correct

Comment: Isn't this just the Boltzmann-Maxwell-Bose-Einstein confusion? The "obviously" probably comes from the fact that indistinguishable balls do not exist in our world (except at the quantum level), so our intuition collapses both cases in to one.

Comment: Isn't this just the number of onto functions from A to B?